# Ranking based on continuous date - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
Bangalore BLR - Bagmane Tech Park  2013-10-11  Data Centre  0
Bangalore BLR - Bagmane Tech Park  2013-10-11  BMS          0  
Bangalore BLR -Bagmane Tech Park   2013-10-12  BMS          0 
Bangalore BLR - Bagmane Tech Park  2013-10-15  BMS          3
```

I am having data like the above. If last column is zero the rank should be made based on all columns. If the date is continuous like 2013-10-11, 2013-10-12 rank should be 1,2... If there is any break in date 2013-10-11, 2013-10-12 and 2013-10-15 again the rank should start from 1 for 2013-10-15

Comment: do you want write function for that rank

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to write a custom aggregate here and I don't think the work involved is going to be trivial.  Then you will need to call it on a window function with an explicit order by.

I think this could be done by storing the dates in an array, then processing the maximum value in the array and doing integer math against the current value.  The problem with this, of course, is performance, and so you would either want to write a function to take the max date of an array in C (or maybe pl/perl?) and then process it from there in SQL.

The process is too complex to give you a working sample here.